# Google Maps inside Famo-us Surface not draggable on mobile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, famo.us, angular-google-maps, famous-angular

I am running [angular-google-maps](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps) inside a [famous-angular](https://github.com/Famous/famous-angular) surface as follows:

```
<fa-app ng-controller="main.common.hello as ctrl">
    <fa-modifier>
        <fa-surface fa-size="[undefined, undefined]">
            <ui-gmap-google-map center="ctrl.map.center" zoom="ctrl.map.zoom" draggable="true" options="ctrl.options"></ui-gmap-google-map>
        </fa-surface>
    </fa-modifier>
</fa-app>
```

The map can be panned and zoomed on the browser but when opened on an iPhone, the map is not responsive to touch events. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure after you initialize your Engine, you also set the Engine's appMode option to false:

```
var Engine = require('famous/core/Engine');

Engine.setOptions({
    appMode:false
});
```

By default, Famo.us assumes you're not using the browser for anything else but a view.

Answer (score 0):

try with this:
https://github.com/IjzerenHein/famous-map

famous-map
Map component for Famo.us, supporting the following map-providers:

Google Maps
Leaflet.js (OpenStreetMap)
Famous-map makes it possible for adding a map-component to the famo.us render-tree. Additionally, famous transitions can be used to pan the map and modifiers can be used to sync the position of renderables with a geographical position.